# Is there any alternative in Android to Apple's `LPMetadataProvider` class

Tags: android, ios, web-scraping, jsoup, html-parsing

Is there any alternative in Android to Apple's `LPMetadataProvider` class, that fetches and provide meta data for a given URL?

I know there are libraries like `jsoup` to get HTML source for a URL but I have to do manual parsing of tags which I want to avoid. Apple's `LPMetadataProvider` provides some basic parsing like icons of the document, title etc by default.